# How To Display One form error in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this in my template and i want only to display username error not all form errors

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns val-error-msg error margin-below">
                {{ error }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could specify a field error with `form.field_name.errors`

like:

```
{% if form.username.errors %}
    {{form.username.errors}}
    # or
    # {{form.username.errors.as_text}}
    # this will remove the `<ul></ul>` tag that django generates by default
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it worked but how can i ignore This field is required. error

Comment: @ChamsAgouni: by setting the `required` option to `False` in the form. Why would you ignore this in the template? It is the wrong place since not displaying the error, will not all of a sudden *get the form validated*.

Comment: because i would to do that by jquery

Comment: @ChamsAgouni, as Willem Van Onsem said, you can ignore what you want by setting `required=False` to the field wanted. It's not a good idea to let Jquery do this as a user can easily edit the form via `Inspect Element` in browsers. all the logic must go to the backend unless jquery will check the requirement before submitting the form, and in the top of that, Django will also check

Comment: how i can change **This field is required** to **Username field is required**

Comment: As I do many times, I set required=False in that field, and after that, when I clean the data, I check whether the field is empty or not `username=self.cleaned_data('username') ____ if not username: self.add_error("username","Username is required").` or you can override the `__init__()` method and edit the error message

Comment: Just import the User model in form, and check whether the email exists or not with `UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email).exists()`.... @ChamsAgouni, it will better when you get stuck on a different issue, to search for it, if you don't find any solution that satisfies your needs, ask a new question. I can't show you how to do that in comments. I want to help you!

Answer (score 2):

Ever field has `.errors` attached to it as well. But note that each field can contain *multiple* errors (for example a password can be too short, *and* contain illegal symbols).

You can access these errors through `{{ form.field.errors }}`, but you already obtain such elements. In case you want to *filter* in the template to only show the errors of - for example - the `username` field, you can do so with an `{% if ... %}` statement:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.name == "username" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns val-error-msg error margin-below">
                {{ error }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```